# VBA to print the same area from multiple worksheets as separate PDF files

Tags: excel, vba, printing, pdf-generation

Going through the stack overflow and other sources on the internet, I found a couple of VBA codes to print multiple active worksheets to separate PDF files.

I would like to use the same printing area in each sheet and save the PDFs as separate files. While trying to (re)create the code, I have now reached the following state and am stuck. More specifically, it seems that the last four lines before "Next" are erroneous (makred in red in Excel VBA Console and causing syntax error), but I am unable to pinpoint what that is so.  Can someone here help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
 Sub SetPrintAreas2()
     Dim sPrintArea As String
     Dim wks As Worksheet

     sPrintArea = "C8:E25"
     For Each wks In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
         wks.PageSetup.PrintArea = sPrintArea
         wks.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
         wks.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA4
         wks.PageSetup.CenterHorizontally = True
         wks.PageSetup.CenterVertically = True
         wks.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
         wks.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
         wks.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
         Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & “\” & wks.Name, _
         Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
         IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
         OpenAfterPublish:=False
     Next
     Set wks = Nothing
     End Sub
```

Thanks to all of you helped make a completely unworkable code full functional. This is how the final working code looks:

```
 Sub SetPrintSameAreasOfActiveSheetsAsPDFs()
     Dim sPrintArea As String
     Dim wks As Worksheet

     sPrintArea = "C8:E25"
     For Each wks In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
         wks.PageSetup.PrintArea = sPrintArea
         wks.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
         wks.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA4
         wks.PageSetup.CenterHorizontally = True
         wks.PageSetup.CenterVertically = True
         wks.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
         wks.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
         wks.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
         Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & wks.Name, _
         Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
         IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
         OpenAfterPublish:=False
     Next
     Set wks = Nothing
     End Sub
```

It prints the Cells between C8:E25 for all selected worksheets in an Excel workbook as PDFs to the same directory. The PDFs take up the name of the worksheet. To use it, after inserting it as a VBA module in the excel sheet, go to the developer tab, Click on Macros, select SetPrintSameAreasOfActiveSheetsAsPDFs() and press "Run".

Comment: What exactly is your question? ("I am stuck" is not a question).

Comment: I would change `Curworksheet.Name` to `wks.name` since you haven't defined  `Curworksheet`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion BigBen. I have now tried to specify what the challenge for me is. GMalc, thanks a lot, I have made the change you suggested. Unfortunately, I am still getting Syntax error and the last four lines before "Next" are being marked by the console.

Comment: Take a look at my edit of your code., since the last five lines are actually one line of code, you need to insert a `, _` on each line, except the last one. `A space followed by an underscore tells VBA that the current statement isn't finished yet but continues on the next line – it's used to split a single line of code over two lines, in order to make the code more readable`

Answer (score 0):

Change this text to below. your “\”  is wrong character.

```
“\”
```

to

```
"\"
```

or

```
Application.PathSeparator
```

Comment: Thank you Dy.Lee and GMalc. After following your advice, the code now works. I will post the final working code in my original question's text so that it is helpful to others as well.